# Можно ли сохранять ссылки на потоки в коллекциях чтобы потом их использовать?

Tags: java, многопоточность, сокет

Есть 100 юзеров(андроид).Они соединяются по сокетам.На данный момент логика такая :У меня есть `HashMap` в котором сохраняю ссылки на созданные потоки`(MyThread t = new MyThread(new Socket)); hashmap.put("key",t)`,а когда подключается юзер, в этот мой класс `(class MyThread extends Thread)` предаю новый созданный сокет и стартую.И вот тут у меня ошибки ....... Когда юзер снова подключается этот же юзер даю ему тот сокет который создавался при первом его подключении.И наконец две проблемы : когда заново стартую `MyThread` вылетает ошибка ...что поток уже работает.. Но это я уже делал каким то образом..но точно не помню.то ли с `isAlive()` или  с `interupt()` ...но как то делал.там у меня выходила ошибка о том что Сокет закрыт..И мой вопрос который мучает меня последний месяц это : можно ли сохранять ссылку на какой то `Сокет` в `Хипе`  для того чтобы потом его использовать? Взять из него `OutputStream` и `InputStream` и писать в них....Если нет то есть ли вариант его переиспользовать?

Comment: Так берите и закрывайте/останавливайте сокет/поток при отключении юзера, при его же подключении возобновляйте. И да, в чем смысл добавления потоков в мапу?

Comment: @GenCloud задачу смог решить..Ссылки на потоки я клал в HashMap чтобы их потом как то мог контролировать менять поля и.т.п.